# Saving and Restoring Fragment State?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using `Fragment`, in this `Fragment` I use from `onSaveInstanceState`for Saving and Restoring `Fragment State` when configuration changes.

But when I get `Log` get me all of `colors 51` :

```
Log.i("LOG", r + "  " + g + "  " + b);
```

Below is my code :

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private Button secondFragmentButton;
    String MY_Red;
    String MY_Green;
    String MY_Blue;
    public SecondFragment()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);

        secondFragmentButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_second_button);
        secondFragmentButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            int r = savedInstanceState.getInt(MY_Red);
            int g = savedInstanceState.getInt(MY_Green);
            int b = savedInstanceState.getInt(MY_Blue);
            Log.i("LOG", r + "  " + g + "  " + b);
            secondFragmentButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v == secondFragmentButton)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(R.string.example_text), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            secondFragmentButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 153, 51));
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(MY_Red, 255);
        outState.putInt(MY_Green, 153);
        outState.putInt(MY_Blue, 51);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried declaring/initializing the key `Strings` as different values? `My_Red`, `My_Green`, and `My_Blue` have the same (`null`) value since they are all uninitialized. Therefore, you're overwriting the bundle every time you call `putInt`, resulting in only one key-value pair in the bundle (`null : 51`) after `onSaveInstanceState`. When `getInt` is called in `onCreateView`, you're essentially performing the same functionality (using the same key) three times, which results in `r`, `g`, and `b` having the same value.

Also, it's good practice to make these keys `static final`.